# How does Eclipse manage different running Java classes

Tags: java, eclipse

If I have a Java file test.java, and run it using Eclipse and it takes long time to process, how come I am able to modify the test.java and run another instance of it at the same time? There should be one test.class file, but Eclipse seems to cache the old one while it runs, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

while the program runs, the class file was already loaded by the class loader to the memory. Therefore the VM no longer needs the .class file. So no problem if the .class file changes on the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

> If I have a java file test.java , and run it using eclipse and it
>   takes long time to process, how come I am able to modify the test.java
>   and run another instance of it at the same time? There should be one
>   test.class file, but eclipse seems cache the old one while it runs,
>   right?

This is not *generally* true, unless you have Automatic project builds and/or Hot Code Deployment turned off. Compatible changes to source files in Eclipse will be propagated to any debug sessions that have loaded the equivalent class, unless the class signature itself was changed.

But yes, each debug session in Eclipse is effectively its own process, with its own classloader.